# Trouble getting scala actors to work over a range in parallel

Tags: list, scala, parallel-processing, actor

A homework assignment for a computer networking software dev class, the prof has us building a port scanner for ports 1-1024 to be run against the local host.  The point of the exercise is to demonstrate task level parallelism using actors.  The prof provided code that scans each port in sequence.  We are to create a version that does this in parallel, with an actor for each processor or hyper thread available to the system.  The goal is to get the time to complete a full scan of all ports 1-1024 and compare the results of a parallel scan against the results of a serial scan.  Here's my code for the parallel scan:

```
import java.net.Socket
import scala.actors._
import Actor._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object LowPortScanner {

  var lastPort = 0
  var openPorts = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var longestRunTime = 00.00
  var results = List[Tuple3[Int, Range, Double]]()

  val host = "localhost"
  val numProcs = 1 to Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
  val portsPerProc = 1024 / numProcs.size
  val caller = self

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //spawn an actor for each processor that scans a given port range
    numProcs.foreach { proc =>
      actor {
        val portRange: Range = (lastPort + 1) to (lastPort + portsPerProc)
        lastPort = lastPort + portsPerProc
        caller ! scan(proc, portRange)
      }
    }

    //catch results from the processor actors above
    def act {
      loop {
        reactWithin(100) {
          //update the list of results returned from scan
          case scanResult: Tuple3[Int, Range, Double] =>
            results = results ::: List(scanResult)

          //check if all results have been returned for each actor
          case TIMEOUT =>
            if (results.size == numProcs.size) wrapUp

          case _ =>
            println("got back something weird from one of the port scan actors!")
            wrapUp
        }
      }
    }

    //Attempt to open a socket on each port in the given range
    //returns a Tuple3[procID: Int, ports: Range, time: Double
    def scan(proc: Int, ports: Range) {
      val startTime = System.nanoTime()
      ports.foreach { n =>
        try {
          println("Processor " + proc + "is checking port " + n)

          val socket = new Socket(host, n)

          //println("Found open port: " + n)
          openPorts += n

          socket.close
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
          //println("While scanning port " + n + " caught Exception: " + e)
        }
      }
      (proc, ports, startTime - System.nanoTime())
    }

    //output results and kill the main actor
    def wrapUp {
      println("These are the open ports in the range 1-1024:")
      openPorts.foreach { port => println(port) }
      results.foreach { result => if (result._3 > longestRunTime) { longestRunTime = result._3} }
      println("Time to scan ports 1 through 1024 is: %3.3f".format(longestRunTime / 1000))
      caller ! exit
    }
  }
}
```

I have a quad core i7, so my numProcs = 8.  On this hardware platform, each proc actor should scan 128 ports (1024/8 = 128).  My intention is for the proc1 actor scan 0 - 128, proc2 should scan 129-256, etc...  However, this isn't what's happening.  Some of the actors end up working on the same range as other actors.  The output sample below illustrates the issue:

Processor 2 is checking port 1
Processor 7 is checking port 385
Processor 1 is checking port 1
Processor 5 is checking port 1
Processor 4 is checking port 1
Processor 8 is checking port 129
Processor 3 is checking port 1
Processor 6 is checking port 257
Processor 1 is checking port 2
Processor 5 is checking port 2
Processor 1 is checking port 3
Processor 3 is checking port 2
Processor 5 is checking port 3
Processor 1 is checking port 4

**EDIT**

Final "working" code:

```
import java.net.Socket
import scala.actors._
import Actor._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object LowPortScanner {

  var lastPort = 0
  var openPorts = ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  var longestRunTime = 00.00
  var results = List[Tuple3[Int, Range, Double]]()

  val host = "localhost"
  val numProcs = 1 to Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
  val portsPerProc = 1024 / numProcs.size
  val caller = self
  val procPortRanges = numProcs.foldLeft(List[Tuple2[Int, Range]]()) { (portRanges, proc) =>
    val tuple2 = (proc.toInt, (lastPort + 1) to (lastPort + portsPerProc))
    lastPort += portsPerProc
    tuple2 :: portRanges
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //spawn an actor for each processor that scans a given port range
    procPortRanges.foreach { proc =>
      actor {
        caller ! scan(proc._1, proc._2)
      }
    }

//catch results from the processor actors above
def act {
  loop {
    reactWithin(100) {
      //update the list of results returned from scan
      case scanResult: Tuple3[Int, Range, Double] =>
        results = results ::: List(scanResult)

      //check if results have been returned for each actor
      case TIMEOUT =>
        if (results.size == numProcs.size) wrapUp

      case _ =>
        println("got back something weird from one of the port scan actors!")
        wrapUp
    }
  }
}

    //Attempt to open a socket on each port in the given range
    //returns a Tuple3[procID: Int, ports: Range, time: Double
    def scan(proc: Int, ports: Range) {
      val startTime = System.nanoTime()
      ports.foreach { n =>
        try {
          println("Processor " + proc + "is checking port " + n)

          val socket = new Socket(host, n)

          //println("Found open port: " + n)
          openPorts += n

          socket.close
        } catch {
          case e: Exception =>
          //println("While scanning port " + n + " caught Exception: " + e)
        }
      }
      (proc, ports, startTime - System.nanoTime())
    }

    //output results and kill the main actor
    def wrapUp {
      println("These are the open ports in the range 1-1024:")
      openPorts.foreach { port => println(port) }
      results.foreach { result => if (result._3 > longestRunTime) { longestRunTime = result._3} }
      println("Time to scan ports 1 through 1024 is: %3.3f".format(longestRunTime / 1000))
      caller ! exit
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On this hardware platform, each proc actor should scan 128 ports (1024/8 = 128).

Except you have

> ```
> val portsPerProc = numProcs.size / 1024
> ```

and 8/1024 is 0. Note that you also have an off-by-one error which causes every actor to scan 1 more port than `portsPerProc`, it should scan either `lastPort to (lastPort + portsPerProc) - 1` or `(lastPort + 1) to (lastPort + portsPerProc)`.

For the future, if you have a different question, you should ask it separately :) But here you have a very obvious race condition: all actors are trying to execute

```
    val portRange: Range = (lastPort + 1) to (lastPort + portsPerProc)
    lastPort = lastPort + portsPerProc
```

concurrently. Think what happens when (for example) actors 1 and 2 execute first line before any actor gets to the second one.

Comment: D'oh!  What a horrifically obvious mistake...  I fixed the portsPerProc issue and the off-by-one error.  It's still not doing what I want it to, however.  Editing the question with the new issue now.

Comment: OK, I had a feeling that's what I was doing.  I edited the orignal post to contain my fix.  I addressed the issue by building a list containing a Tuple2 to hold the ranges for each proc, and modified the call to scan so that it used the tuple to call scan with a specific proc ID and unique ranges.  Not sure why my wrapUp method is never called...  I'll post a separate question for that per your prior advise.  Thanks!